# How to efficiently encode readings below or above range of measurement

Tags: delphi, types, pascal, numeric, medical

Using numeric variables, what is the best practice to encode results of measurements that are below or above the range provided by the instrumentation (e.g. TSH < 0.001)? In the specific case this is needed for a medical project, but the problem is expected to apply to any kind of measurement. In my own research I couldn’t find a satisfactory solution up to now.

Generally, this class of problems is addressed in medical data formats, e.g. HL7, but there, numeric values are basically represented as strings. Is there an efficient way to do this with numeric data types (apart from a separate flag variable indicating if the result is within, below or above the cut-off value of the range of measurement)?

This should preferably be a cross-platform solution independent of the used processor architecture and being compatible with Pascal or Object Pascal, but elegant solutions in other programming languages are welcome, too.

Comment: Thyroid-stimulating hormone from the adenohypophysis?

Comment: Yes, but this is only used to serve as an example.

Comment: Not clear. What's wrong with the flag?

Comment: Returning to the actual topic: I think you need to be more precise. For instance, what do you mean by "efficiently"? If the cut-off value is 0.001 you can easily see if `x` is below this value by a simple comparison: `x < 0.001`. Depending on the application, it might make sense to remove these values or set them to `0`. It's a bit hard to give any advice without all the details and specific requirements.

Comment: The question is about encoding. The readouts should be stored in a variable, and the information if they are below or above a certain cut-off value should be retained, since these data will be used in later steps. For this purpose, "x = 0" is definitively not a substitute for "x < 0.001".

Comment: You mean that the information must be stored in the variable (each sample) itself, and that it isn't enough to have an "external"/"global" variable named `MinCutoff = 0.001` to compare against? (For instance, the cut-off value is different for each sampled value.) If so, you could stop using `Double` as the type for each sample, and instead use `TSample = record Value: Double; WithinBounds: Boolean end`

Comment: @Olivier: Perhaps nothing is wrong with a flag. I wanted to know if there is a more elegant solution before I start with coding.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: I am planning to refine an existing software that processes medical lab results. Since it has to deal with results from different labs, a global MinCutoff variable wouldn't be too helpful. The record type suggested by you might be a solution. I hat already considered a similary approach, but I wanted to know if a more elegant way has been suggested.

Comment: Then perhaps a record? `TSample = record Value, LowCutoff, HighCutoff: Double; PatientID: Integer; SampledDate: TDateTime end;` Then you can add methods to it: `MySample.IsWithinRange`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, that may be a not so bad way.

Answer (score 1):

The `double` values, in their IEEE definition, have already some "special values".

```
0 11111111111 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 ≙ 7FF0 0000 0000 000016 
    ≙ +∞ (positive infinity)
1 11111111111 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 ≙ FFF0 0000 0000 000016 
    ≙ −∞ (negative infinity)
```

You may reuse these "flags" for below/above range values.

Every language can recognize those values, e.g. Delphi/FPC `Math.pas` unit defines `NegInfinity` and `Infinity` if I remember correctly:

```
  Infinity    =  1.0 / 0.0;
  NegInfinity = -1.0 / 0.0;
```

One side advantage is that they will be converted as text properly as non numbers (`+INF/-INF`), so it may help debugging and tracing those values.

Of course, you should detect and avoid computing with those values (e.g. a mean/R² or curve fitting), which may break your calculation with the correct values. But the result will probably be so obviously wrong (infinity will preempt other values in most mathematical operations) that it could be not too difficult to track this problem.

Check [this article as reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: From comments: *The readouts should be stored in a variable, and the information if they are below or above a certain cut-off value should be retained, since these data will be used in later steps. For this purpose, "x = 0" is definitively not a substitute for "x < 0.001"*. Substituting the value with +/-INF is not enough.

Comment: I didn't read all the comments. So he doesn't need a flag, he just needs to check if the value is within range - it will be almost as fast as a flag.

Comment: Not only that, the max/min limits, time-stamp, sample-ID must follow the measured value at all times. So, the proposal by @Andreas, to put it all in a record provided with methods/properties to correctly extract validation is a good practice. In our organisation that is common when storing time series data into a database.